# Browser not picking CSS class

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have following HTML:

```
            <div id="geo" class="myright">
                <img class="rounded-extra" src="images/mapa-bhcom.jpg" width="100%" height="100%"  >

                <br/>
                <br/>
                <br/>

                <h3>BHcom</h3>
                <p style="color: #858585; margin-top: -10px;">Ne dozvolite da Vam promaknu najbitnije informacije!</p>

                <ul class="connect">
                    <li class="email">
                        <a href="mailto:info@pagescroller.com">Pošaljite e-mail direktno</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class = "twitter">
                        <a href="http://twitter.com/remacez" target="_blank">Pratite nas na Twitteru</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>

            </div>
```

And I have this CSS in my one and only CSS file imported in html:

```
#geo .connect .email{
    background: transparent url('../images/icon_mail.png') no-repeat 0 0;
}

#geo .connect .twitter{
    background: transparent url('../images/icon_twitter.png') no-repeat 0 0;
}

#geo .connect a{
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0 0 2px 29px;
    margin: 10px 0 0;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #666;
}

#geo .connect a:hover{
    color: #333;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

However, neither Firefox or Chrome pick up my styles related to email above. The CSS selector for twitter is just fine. What am I missing?

Comment: I setup the http://jsfiddle.net/timgreen/SzkmV/, it looks fine. Please show why it doesn't work.

Comment: It doesn't load my email image. And I don't see in Chrome inspector that this <li> has any style attached. My image is 100% on that path on server. :(

Comment: I tried on my chrome inspector it has background style on both <li> :)

Comment: Are you sure it named correctly in CSS(gif,jpg,png)?

Comment: I took the fiddle that Tim setup and replaced your background-images: http://jsfiddle.net/6dC2U/. It works fine with the new icon I used for both selectors in Chrome and IE 9. Check to make sure your url is pointing to the right place.

Comment: Checked my URLs, everything fine. Still not getting result. Mail icon is missing even when I put same URL for images for both .email and .twitter class.

Comment: one interesting behavior I noticed: If I replace order of CSS selectors for mail and twitter classes in css file, only background defined for last is showed. So because of that I think error has to do with my css selectors being improper.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `background: transparent` property from the background property. Chrome picks this up weirdly and makes it 100% transparent so the image will be there but not displayed.

```
background-image:url(../images/whatever.jpg) no-repeat;
```

This will work with every browser for background transparency if you need it and do not want the child content effected.

```
div {
 -khtml-opacity:.50; 
 -moz-opacity:.50; 
 -ms-filter:"alpha(opacity=50)";
  filter:alpha(opacity=50);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=0.5);
  opacity:.50; 
}
```

If you don't want transparency to affect the entire container and its children, check this workaround. You must have an absolutely positioned child with a relatively positioned parent.
You can check a demo at http://www.impressivewebs.com/css-opacity-that-doesnt-affect-child-elements/

Comment: Could you go ahead and add the relevant code from the additional link regarding the second bit about the non-entire-container transparency fix? That way, if the link becomes a dead link later, the answer will still be preserved.

Comment: tried removing transparent property and still have same issue